# How to count checkboxes has checked in DataTable for show and hidden Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I use datatable for data collection, I use the checkbox feature in the datatable to select the data that needs to be executed in the form of a delete and edit button, my plan to delete and edit buttons will appear together when the checkbox is selected in 1 data, for checkboxes selected more than 1 button will appear just delete it. I have a problem here that is the button does not want to appear, following my code

Table and Button Code :

```
<div class="col s12 m12 l12">
  <button id="hapus" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" style="display: none">Hapus</button>
  <button id="status" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" style="display: none">Ubah Status</button>

 <table id="example" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Judul</th>
        <th>Tag</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Tanggal</th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var xx = document.getElementById("status");
        var xy = document.getElementById("hapus");

        var $checkboxes = $('#example td input[type="checkbox"]');

        $checkboxes.change(function(){
            var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;

            if (countCheckedCheckboxes == 1){
                xx.style.display = "block";
                xy.style.display = "block";
            } else if (countCheckedCheckboxes >= 2) {
                xx.style.display = "none";
                xy.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                xx.style.display = "none";
                xy.style.display = "none";
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get and count the checkboxes again inside your change method.  You cant reuse the variable $checkboxes

Comment: I've tried this code in a normal table and the results can work, but after I install the datatable it doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked if the event is firing when you click on the Checkboxes?

Comment: What do you mean by this code? 
var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;

Comment: i would put an Alert(countCheckedCheckboxes); Just to make sure that it really works and check if the function is being triggered

Comment: I've tried it on console.log (), but not show anything

Comment: So the problem is: method not firing.

Comment: Put an Alert bellow $checkboxes variable to see if some checkboxes is found..

Comment: Yes, but how can I get a method that can check firing the datatable?

Comment: for checkboxes in the data collection method its work

Comment: You need to show exactly how are you filling your Datatable.

Comment: But, as i told you Before, i think you cant reuse the variable $checkboxes, because when that variable is filled, the checkboxes isnt checked